# Does .NET DateTime.ToLocalTime persist across DST changes?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, dst

In the UK the clocks changed on 25/10/2015

If I ran the code below on 24/10/2015 and again on 26/10/2015, would the same output be produced?

From my knowledge of how the DateTime stuff works in C# I am assuming yes but I wanted to double check as it is critical for my application.

```
// January date outside of DST
var januaryDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine(januaryDate.ToLocalTime().ToString());

// April date inside DST
var aprilDate = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine(aprilDate.ToLocalTime().ToString());
```

Comment: Local time means to whatever your *current timezone* is. Even different users on the same machine may be using different timezones.  If you care about offsets use DateTimeOffset, not DateTime. If it's critical (as it is eg in air travel), check NodaTime as well - it contains the latest IANA timezone database so you won't have to guess that BST means (Brazil or British) or what's the correct offset for Dallas

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks but unfortunately am stuck with the DateTime type. Assume for this question that it is the same user on the same machine.

Comment: Then you are in trouble. At least, specify the date type (ie Local or UTC) because right now it's Unspecified and treated as UTC. `ToLocalTime()` applied a 2 hour offset on my machine which is `+2:00`. Guess that also answers your question, but also shows why you are in trouble. Unless you make **sure** the offset or the kind are stored with your date (ie in the database, files etc) and properly set before processing, you can have unexpected results

Comment: For example, datetimes loaded from a database are Unpsecified. SQL Server and other databases *do* support types with offsets, but if you are going to use them as `DateTime` you'll still face a conversion.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know I'm in trouble, but still need an answer to the question! I've edited the code to be explicit about DateTimeKind.Utc

Comment: DST will be applied properly. Just tried this in LinqPad. The result was +2 for the first date, +3 for the second. `ToLocalTime` uses the timezone rules, not just the timezone offset

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that. The question is whether you get a different output before/after the DST change

Comment: No, you don't. ToLocalTime uses the timezone rules, not just the offset.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos are you good to answer the question then, posting the output for your +2:00 offset showing the output either side of a DST change?

Comment: ToLocalTime uses the current timezone's adjustment rules to determine the offset in effect at the specified DateTime's value, not the offset in effect at the current time. So no they should not give different answers when run on different days. Note however that on older system's there isn't really a notion of the adjustment rules changing over time. which is why the docs have a warning about using this method on XP systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ToLocalTime uses the current timezone's rules, not just the current offset to calculate local time. Calling `ToLocalTime` on `2015-01-01 00:00` and `2015-04-01 00:00` will return the same result whether the call is made before or after a DST change.

My current offset is +2, but calling the sample code returns `1/1/2015 2:00:00 am` in the first case and  `1/4/2015 3:00:00 am` in the second.

Checking the reference source for [ToLocalTime](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,5f39b12e679532c6,references) shows that the method checks whether DST needs to be applied for a specific date before returning the local time:

```
Boolean isDaylightSavings = false;
Boolean isAmbiguousLocalDst = false;
Int64 offset = TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffsetFromUtc(this, TimeZoneInfo.Local,
                           out isDaylightSavings, out isAmbiguousLocalDst).Ticks;

long tick = Ticks + offset;
//various validations
//...
return new DateTime(tick, DateTimeKind.Local, isAmbiguousLocalDst);
```

Comment: Nice one! This has helped me a lot, hopefully will help others too